# Nginx Configg http_origin contains regex

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config

I have my nginx conf setup like so for a personal project I am working on.  Mainly to learn nginx better.

```
upstream search {
  server 127.0.0.1:2502;
  keepalive 15;
}

server {
  listen 80;
    server_name search.baw;

  location / {

    if ($request_method = 'DELETE') {
      return 500 "{message: 'Get outta here with that!'}";
    }

    if ($http_origin !~ /myapp.baw|otherapp.baw/) {
      return 500 "{message: 'Well well well, you are now allowed!'}";
    }

    proxy_pass http://search;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Keep-Alive";
    proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection "Keep-Alive";
  }

}
```

Everything seems to work perfectly except for the regex to match the origin host name.  Locally the host names are `http://myapp.baw:2501` and `http://otherapp.baw:2501`.  How would I write the regex to match either of these host names?

Thanks!

Comment: The regex should not be enclosed within `/`s. That's a Perl operator I think.

Comment: @RichardSmith Nginx uses PCRE, so it is valid.

Comment: Your question implies that it doesn't work. The `/`s in your regex are treated literally, so Nginx is attempting to match an `$http_origin` that does not contain `/myapp.baw` or `otherapp.baw/`. You should be using `myapp.baw|otherapp.baw`. You can enclose it in quotes or parentheses if you prefer (but not `/`s, as it changes the meaning).

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a try!

Comment: @RichardSmith Hey, Richard.  Could you make your comment the answer and I can accept it?  What you explained worked!  Thank you.